# Need libraries for compare speech tracks (pronunciation)

Tags: .net, audio, speech

There are two speech sample (in wav or mp3). Need to compare both and set some coeff of comparing.

It's need to training pronunciation like Rosetta Stone.

Prefer libs for .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the System.Speech libraries in the .NET Framework:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145021.aspx

This page shows how to use Synthesis to speak words, and Recognition to listen and recognize what a user is saying:  http://www.mperfect.net/speechSamples/